# Los datos del servidor en jsp no se muestran como corresponde en la tabla

Tags: jsp

tengo un pequeño programa que hace una consulta al servidor sql del que extrae uno datos pero no consigo hacer que me lo muestre cada dato al que le corresponde.

La salida que obtengo ahora mismo es esta:

[image: imagen:]

Id Alumno, Nombre y teléfono esta bien pero el nombre del curso es el que no consigo hacer que salga bien, la salida correcta sería:

1. 1, VICTOR, 2212134, PRIMERO ESO
2. 2, PACO, 984747321, PRIMERO ESO
3. 3, PEPE, 964321345, SEGUNDO ESO

Por un lado tengo un datosAlumnos.java:

```
   public class datosAlumnos 
{
Connection miconexion;
String cadsql;

    public datosAlumnos() {
         miconexion=MySQL_Util.Conectar("localhost","root","", "ciclosfp");             
    }
    
    public ResultSet getResultado() {
        
       cadsql ="select a.ID, a.NOMBRE, a.TELEFONO, cursos.NOMBRE from alumnos a, cursos "
               + "where cursos.id = a.CURSO;";
        
        ResultSet rset=
                 MySQL_Util.Sel_Consulta(miconexion, cadsql);
        return rset;
    }
}
```

Y un datosCursos.java:

```
    public class datosCursos 
{
Connection miconexion;
String cadsql;
private ResultSet rsIDAlum;
private ResultSet rsFCurso;

    public datosCursos() {
         miconexion=MySQL_Util.Conectar("localhost","root","", "ciclosfp");             
    }

       public ResultSet getRsIDAlum() {
        rsIDAlum=MySQL_Util.Sel_Consulta(miconexion, "select * from alumnos");
        return rsIDAlum;
    }

    public void setRsIDAlum(ResultSet rsIDAlum) {
        this.rsIDAlum = rsIDAlum;
    }
    
    
    public ResultSet getRsFCursos() {
        try
        {
        String cadsql2 ="select cursos.nombre from cursos inner join alumnos on cursos.ID=alumnos.ID where alumnos.ID="+rsIDAlum.getString("ID");
            rsFCurso=(MySQL_Util.Sel_Consulta(miconexion, cadsql2));
       
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            rsFCurso=null;
        }
        return rsFCurso;
    }

    public void setRsFCursos(ResultSet rsFCurso) {
        this.rsFCurso = rsFCurso;
    }

}
```

y el índex para mostrar:

```
    <h1><h:outputText value="Datos de los alumnos:"/></h1>
          
            <h:dataTable border="1" value="#{datosAlumnos.resultado}"
                         var="fila">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Id Alumno"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{fila.ID}"/>
                </h:column>  
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Nombre Alumno"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{fila.NOMBRE}"/>
                </h:column>  
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Telefono"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{fila.TELEFONO}"/>
                </h:column> 
                     <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" >
                        <h:outputText value="Nombre Curso"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:dataTable value="#{datosCursos.rsFCursos}" var="forma" > 
                        <h:column>
                            <h:outputText value="#{forma.nombre}"/>
                        </h:column>                   
                    </h:dataTable>                            
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

La cosa es que la consulta de los cursos muestra el resultado en las 3 tablas de los alumnos y he probado de todo y no consigo hacer que funcione.
No encuentro información sobre si se puede usar alias en jsp para las tablas, ya que como hay dos tablas que se llaman igual (nombre[alumnos] y nombre[cursos]) no puedo simplemente poner fila.nombre porque me saca el nombre de los alumnos dos veces.

Update: He modificado el fichero DatosCurso.java ya que creo que este es el camino correcto pero ahora en Nombre Curso no me muestra ningún dato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno probando cosas he dado con la solución y era mucho mas simple que lo que tenia, el problema era que estaba enlazando una clave primaria errónea entre tablas.
No es necesario tampoco crear dos paginas .java, en un único archivo se puede poner las dos instrucciones.

datosAlumnos.java:

```
    public class datosAlumnos 
{
Connection miconexion;
String cadsql;
 private ResultSet principal;
    private ResultSet secundario;

    public datosAlumnos() {
         miconexion=MySQL_Util.Conectar("localhost","root","", "ciclosfp");             
    }

      public ResultSet getPrincipal() {
        String consultaPrincipal="select curso, id, nombre, telefono from alumnos";
        principal=MySQL_Util.Sel_Consulta(miconexion, consultaPrincipal);
        return principal;
    }

    /**
     * @return the secundario
     */
    public ResultSet getSecundario() {
   
        try{
        String consultaSecundaria="select nombre from cursos where  ID=";
               consultaSecundaria=consultaSecundaria+principal.getString("curso");
                   
                 secundario=MySQL_Util.Sel_Consulta(miconexion, consultaSecundaria);
                  return secundario;
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
       {return null;}
        
    }
```

index:

```
        <h:dataTable border="1" value="#{datosAlumnos.principal}"
                 var="fila">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Id Alumno"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{fila.ID}"/>
        </h:column>  
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Nombre Alumno"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{fila.NOMBRE}"/>
        </h:column>  
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Telefono"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{fila.TELEFONO}"/>
        </h:column> 
             <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header" >
                <h:outputText value="Nombre Curso"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:dataTable value="#{datosAlumnos.secundario}" var="forma" > 
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{forma.nombre}"/>
                </h:column>                   
            </h:dataTable>                            
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```